# continuing echo of two different statements back to same line

Tags: bash, shell, file, output, echo

I know using echo -n option , we can update the output in same line .

But i have different scenario :

```
       echo "Currently reading file :"
       if [some_condition];then
           echo -n $file_read
       else
           echo -n "Skipping file read:" $file_skip
       fi

       echo "successfully completed"
```

Current output :

```
         Currently reading file :   
         0  1  2  Skipping file read : 3 Skipping file read 4  5  6  7  8  

         Completed reading files successfully
```

Expecting output 1 :

```
          Currently reading file : 
          0 1 2 .....9 10 11 ....

          Skipping file read : 4 5 6 ....12 13
```

OR

Expecting Output 2:

for this i can use  -en  option for this

```
        currently Reading file : only latest file no  
        Skipped these files : 1 2 9 15 21 ....
```

OR
Any other best way possible

Is there any better way to display this output scenario . Files range may be between 1 to 2000 .

I even tried displaying only the latest output  using

```
        echo -en "$file_read \r"
```

But this also wont look good when a file is skipped reading .

Comment: Please post the sample inputs in code tags too in your post.

Comment: Look for 'ANSI' escape character if your terminal support them

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 input is different files starting from file_1 to file_n .

Answer (score 1):

You can declare firstly the initial values of FIRST_ROW or SECOND_ROW as you with
For example:

```
SECOND_ROW="Skipping file read : "
```

Then you assign the outputs you need in 2 different variables for 'Expecting output 1'

```
if [some_condition];then
       FIRST_ROW= "$FIRST_ROW $file_read"
else
       SECOND_ROW= "$SECOND_ROW $file_skip"
fi
```

And finally you can print the desired output using

```
echo
```

and custom strings as you wish